# How to implement security in a spring application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I'm creating a spring application for a college project.

```
package com.sales.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{ 
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/showProducts.html", "/showOrders.html", "/showCustomers.html","/newOrder.html","/addProduct.html","/addCustomer.html")
    .authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin();
  }

 private static final String ENCODED_PASSWORD = "$2y$12$i4Cl5SZgrPFItSz/G5cvTObf0sqzHszwwKMZ4pQeUlElY1BR7KxdO"; //password is "user" encrypted using BCrypt


 @Override
 protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
     auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
         .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
         .withUser("user").password(ENCODED_PASSWORD).roles("USER");
 }


 @Bean
 public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
     return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
 }
}
```

I've taken the code from user TwiN at [Java Spring Security - User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder() is deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49847791/java-spring-security-user-withdefaultpasswordencoder-is-deprecated)

I have changed the hash to be "user" and have confirmed it's definitely "user" using https://bcrypt-generator.com/

but no matter what now, the login page won't allow me to login and says that my login details are incorrect
 [here's what my application looks like after entering a username="user" and password ="user"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSuwu.png)

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/q/49847791/6518928 ?

Comment: @JaimeS I have done that now but now it says my credential's are incorrect. I know i haven't entered them in wrong. I took the code from the answer by TwiN and replaced my userDetailsService() method with their code.

Comment: @DylanCreaven, As you said you have used cred as per TwiN's answer. Have you used username as **user** and password as **secret123**. Please update the question with updated code

Comment: @PatelRomil I have updated the question accordingly

Comment: @DylanCreaven, I have posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of methods to implement security in spring i can't follow what you are doing but here's my github repo [Spring Boot Security](https://github.com/Be55am/Spring-security/tree/in-memory-authentication) you can shange the branches to see diffrent ways to apply security, select the branche "in memory" its the semplest one.

Answer (score 0):

Add below properties in *application.properties*

```
spring.security.user.name = user
spring.security.user.password = user
spring.security.user.roles = USER
```

OR

Add these to the current *SecurityConfig* class

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
```

Comment: When i try the first method i get the error "Syntax error on token "name", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token" and when i try the second way there's no difference it's still just saying my login details are incorrect

Comment: @DylanCreaven, Can you share the logs in question, Have you tried with the second option?

Comment: I have tried the second way, my code is the near identical to question above but with the Configuration and EnabaleGlobalMethodSecurity snippets added to above my SecurityConfig class. The username and password is both just "user" too.

Comment: @Dylan Are still unable to perform the login. Can you see the spring security generated password in console while starting the application. Of there is any other error in console please share it